# Sending anonymous invitations to Google Calendar events

Tags: google-calendar

Is there a way to send invitations in Google Calendar without including yourself at all (either as a guest or as the organizer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [seen evidence](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/apps-apis/thread?tid=7ecdeec482b255bb) that what you are asking is impossible. But you may be able to work around this by creating a generic, anonymous Gmail account and sending the invitations from that account.